# soap Ui response dynamically

Tags: java, soap, groovy, mocking, soapui

I need to find the way to generate an Soap UI Mock Response dynamically.
I have this example of request (we must focus on the field elem into listelem):

**Request**

```
 <soapenv:Level1>
      <v1:listelem>
         <v2:elem>
            <v11:data1>?</v11:data1>
            <v11:data2>?</v11:data2>
         </v2:elem>
         <v2:elem>
            <v11:data1>?</v11:data1>
            <v11:data2>?</v11:data2>
         </v2:elem>
         <v2:elem>
            <v11:data1>?</v11:data1>
            <v11:data2>?</v11:data2>
         </v2:elem>
      </v1:listelem>
   </soapenv:Level1>
```

in my **request** I can find **from 0 to n elements** and I must translate those data into the **response** the field like that:
**Response**

```
 <soapenv:Level1>
          <v1:OtherData>
          </v1:OtherData>
          <v1:EvenOtherData>
          </v1:EvenOtherData>
          <v1:listelem>
             <v2:elem>
                <v11:data1>?</v11:data1>
                <v11:data2>?</v11:data2>
                <v11:respose>?</v11:respose>
             </v2:elem>
             <v2:elem>
                <v11:data1>?</v11:data1>
                <v11:data2>?</v11:data2>
                <v11:respose>?</v11:respose>
             </v2:elem>
             <v2:elem>
                <v11:data1>?</v11:data1>
                <v11:data2>?</v11:data2>
                <v11:respose>?</v11:respose>
             </v2:elem>
          </v1:listelem>
       </soapenv:Level1>
```

How can I create the N nodes (named `element`) in the response? I have to add another node after the other nodes. I have tried to do it with a script but I was not successful.

Comment: Why is the last part of your post in Italian? :P

Comment: you have rigth, the translation is:
how can I create the N nodes (named ** element **) in the answer?
 i must add bottom of the other nodes, another node.
i have tried to did it by script but i am not successful.

Comment: I'll edit your question for you. Next time you can do it yourself with an [edit] instead of using comments for that.

Comment: https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-mocking/creating-dynamic-mockservices/  try this using a script

Answer (score 0):

I added namsespace declarations to your example.

```
<soapenv:Level1 xmlns:soapenv="1"  xmlns:v1="v1" xmlns:v2="v2" xmlns:v11="v11">
```

Try this script in SOAP Mock Response

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holderRequest = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )
def holderResponse = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( mockResponse.responseContent )

listelemRequest =  holderRequest.getDomNode("//v1:listelem")
Level1Response =  holderResponse.getDomNode("//soapenv:Level1")
listelemResponse =  holderResponse.getDomNode("//v1:listelem")

//Coppy listelem from request to response
listelem = listelemResponse.getOwnerDocument().importNode(listelemRequest, true)
Level1Response.replaceChild(listelem,listelemResponse) 

//List nodes of elements
nodes =  holderResponse.getDomNodes("//v2:elem")

for(node in nodes){ 
    def nodeHolder  = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("""<v11:response xmlns:v11="v11">?</v11:response>""")
    def itemNode = nodeHolder.getDomNode("//v11:response" )
    def responseElem = node.getOwnerDocument().importNode(itemNode,true)
    node.appendChild(responseElem)
}

mockResponse.setResponseContent(holderResponse.getXml())
```

Script copies listelem from request to response and adds items "response"